# Matplotlib subplot missing grid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-image, imshow

I am trying to plot two graphs.
 First one displayed randomly generated pixels and the second one eroded one.
When I plot those subplots first one does not show the grid, also Y axis numbering are reversed and origin point shifted a little bit.
Could you please advice how can i fix those issues?

[image]

Here is my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import disk,erosion

x=np.random.randint(2,size=(10,10))
se=disk(1)
y=erosion(x,se)

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['w', 'k'])

ax0.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
ax0.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
ax0.set_title("Input image")

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
ax1.set_title("Eroded Image")

ax0.imshow(x,interpolation='none', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax1.imshow(y,interpolation='none', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

plt.rc('grid', linestyle="-", color='red')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the code to reverse the y axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from skimage.morphology import disk,erosion

x=np.random.randint(2,size=(10,10))
se=disk(1)
y=erosion(x,se)

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['w', 'k'])

ax0.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
ax0.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
ax0.set_title("Input image")

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
ax1.set_title("Eroded Image")

ax0.imshow(x,interpolation='none', cmap=cmap)
ax1.imshow(y,interpolation='none', cmap=cmap)

plt.rc('grid', linestyle="-", color='red')
ax0.invert_yaxis()
ax1.invert_yaxis()

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

just use the `.invert_yaxis()` method after plotting the content. This the result:

[image]

Regarding the ticks: you are plotting a matrix through `imshow()`, so the x and y values are not continuous along their axis, they are concentreted in the cells of the matrix. The ticks that `imshow()` shows are referred to the center of each cells, because this is the information you are interested in. There is not a 'origin' that pass through the intersection of a 'x' and 'y' axes in a carthesian plane, because this is not a carthesian plane. You are translating the content of a matrix in an image, so `imshow()` shows you the ticks at each cell center.